# How to specialize a template member in a normal class for a template type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class which is not a template but has a template function as follows:

```
class Table {
public:
 template <typename t>
 t Get(int, int);
};
```

And I want to specialize this for a template type say for a fixed_string defined like this:

```
template <int max>
class fixed_string {
};
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As @ForEveR pointed, there's no patial function template specialization, you can only provide a full specialization version for it. Such as:

```
template <>
fixed_string<9> Table::Get<fixed_string<9>>(int, int);
```

and then call it by

```
table.Get<fixed_string<9>>(0, 0);
```

But you can overload function template, such as:

```
class Table {
public:
    template <typename t>
    t Get(int, int);
    template <int max>
    fixed_string<max> Get(int, int);
};
```

and then

```
Table table;
table.Get<9>(0, 0);
```

or

```
class Table {
public:
    template <typename t>
    t Get(int, int);
    template <int max, template<int> class T=fixed_string>
    T<max> Get(int, int);
};
```

and then

```
Table table;
table.Get<9>(0, 0); // or table.Get<9, fixed_string>(0, 0);
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/acgL37)

Comment: I tried that already but compiler did not resolve the overload. I will try again. Thanks.

Comment: @user3612009 What error did you get? I've added a live demo link in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, just double checked and I was issuing the call incorrectly as Get<fixed_string<5>> which gets resolved to the template version. Thanks.

Comment: @user3612009 Glad can help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, like this:

```
Table table;
table.Get<fixed_string<100>>(3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no partial function template specialization, so, you can only specialize it for fixed_string with known max.

```
template<>
fixed_string<100> Table::get(int, int)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definition:

```
template<int max>
 fixed_string<max> Get(int, int);
```

Call:

```
Table obj;
fixed_string<20> str = obj.Get<20>(1, 2);
```